# Resample pandas Series by group

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to resample a pandas Series without a datetime index, by group of `n`

Since the I googled the exact title of this question and didn't find and answer, I guess I only have an issue of wording my question properly, and therefore it's likely this question is a duplicate (if so I'll delete it).

Also, I've been trying with `Series.rolling` ans `Series.groupby` but I didn't achieve the intended result.

I could do it with a dirty loop but I assume a cleaner, more canonical, and more performant way exists.

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,11,22,33,44,444,555,666])
# 0       1
# 1       2
# 2       3
# 3       4
# 4      11
# 5      22
# 6      33
# 7      44
# 8     444
# 9     555
# 10    666
# dtype: int64

# What I want:
s.resampleByGroupOfN(4).max().reset_index()
# 0       4
# 1       44
# 2       666
```

**Edit:** The solution bellow proposed by Derek O works like a charm. Just in case you're like me (ie: often too lazy to read the comments) Umar.H pointed out a more compact version of it: `s.groupby(s.index // 4).max()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is reindex your series with repeated values for your groups, and then apply a groupby.

For example:

```
s.index = [x//4 for x in s.index]
```

The index of s becomes: `Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype='int64')`

Then apply the groupby:

```
>>> s.groupby(level=0).max()
0      4
1     44
2    666
```

Comment: I'd find surprising none of Series's method is meant to do this, (my first guess was rolling with an offset but there seams to be no such thing). 
Nevertheless your solution is pretty elegant, I'll use that :). Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, I am a bit surprised there isn't any groupby to directly perform this operation, although in my experience groupbys are usually performed on other columns in a DataFrame. if you found the answer helpful, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that anyone with the same question is directed to the answer as well, thanks!

Comment: ah missed your answer - I think `s.groupby(s.index // 4).max()` is more compact ;)

Comment: @Umar.H oh for sure. you can solve the problem with a one-liner but I broke it up to show how the index in `s` is modified prior to the groupby. although it's beyond what @QuantumPotatoe was asking, they may want to modify the index of s, or they might just the groupby result in which case your solution is more succinct